# synchronous http request using async & await - angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, async-await

I need to call an API and validate a data and then depending on the result of the API I need to re-route the user. All this should happen before the page is renderd.

I'm working in angular 5

```
validateUrl() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(async params => {
        if (params['id']) {
            let rep = await this.validateRepUrl(params['id']);
            if (rep) {
                this.router.navigate(['/request', rep]);
            } else {
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
            }
        }
    });
}

validate(url) {
    let validationDone;
    const updated = new Promise<Boolean>(resolve => validationDone = resolve);
    this.startupService.validateUrl(url)
    .subscribe(result => {
        if (result && result.data > 0) {
            validationDone(result.data);
        }
    }, err => {
        validationDone(null);
    });
}
```

Comment: You can use route guards: https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards this is the right way to validate if a route can be accessed or not.

Comment: @ChristianBenseler But within the route guards, it's not possible to access the router params.

Comment: [Route Resolvers](https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/)

Comment: Yes, it is. Take a look at this blog post: https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3 you have access to an ActivatedRouteSnapshot object.

Comment: @ChristianBenseler I will try it. Thanks

Comment: You're not `return`ing anything from `validateUrl` that you could call `.subscribe()` upon?